# Regex that will only allow alphanumeric characters and underscore and specific placeholder inside curly braces

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want a regex that will only allow alphanumeric characters and underscore and specific placeholder inside curly braces.

Valid examples:

```
test{placeholder}
test_{placeholder}
test_123_{placeholder}
test
test_123
test123
{placeholder}_test
test{placeholder}test
And any combination of above.
```

This is what I came up with:

```
[^-A-Za-z0-9_]|^\{placeholder\}
```

The way I understand this is:

`[^-A-Za-z0-9_]` - Don't allow any other characters than a-z 0-9 and underscore.

`|^\{placeholder\}` - Or anything that doesn't say {placeholder}

But it doesn't work and I am not sure why.

Here is [demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rzA)

Please help.

Comment: Strange that you want to allow alphanumeric characters and underscore and then write a regex of which you explain that it doesn't allow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|{placeholder})+$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[A-Za-z0-9_]` - a word char: letter, digit, `_`
  - `|` - or
  - `{placeholder}` - a specific substring
- `)+` - end of group, repeat 1 or more times
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGaxTR/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5BA-Za-z0-9_%5D%7C%7Bplaceholder%7D)%2B%24):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !